# Passing value in function properly in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-init

I have the following function which takes variable description as parameter

```
$scope.relsingle = function(description) {
    console.log(description);
    var url = $scope.url+'/api/descrelation?limit=4&description='+description;
    $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.apgresponse = data;
    })
};
```

I use the following approach to pass this value in the html page

```
ng-init="relsingle(prodres[0].description)"
```

This value of prodres[0].description comes from here. 
[image: Console output]

And value of prodres comes from here

```
$scope.prodat = function(id) {

    var uri = $scope.url+'/api/getproduct?productid='+id;
    console.log(uri);
    $http.get(uri).success(function(data) {
      console.log(id);
      console.log(data);
      $scope.prodres = data;
    })
  };
```

when i log the value of description in console in the relsingle function.

> console.log(description);

This gives me value undefined.

Comment: I think ng-init was build to handle expression only not sure it works well with running function.

Comment: What is `prodres`?

Comment: relsingle is a custom function i defined

Comment: you are not returning anything from the function. pls return a value from `relsingle`

Comment: What specifically is undefined? Please take a few mintes to read through [ask]

Comment: @Sravan where do you expect it to be returned to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it like this with `ngInit` because it runs only once and when it happence variable `prodres` is not yet available because it comes from async call.

What you can however do is to make `ngInit` execute only after the value for `prodres` has been resolved:

```
<div ng-if="prodres" ng-init="relsingle(prodres[0].description)">...</div>
```

Because `ngIf` has higher priority ngInit will execute only after `ngIf`.

Comment: still a bad practice to use `ng-init` for this in the first place

Comment: So what approach should i follow please explain a suitable approach with detail for this kind of problems

Comment: @charlietfl I agree that ngInit might be not the nicest approach in many cases.

Comment: @VikasAnand the norm would be to make the second call within the success of the first one ... in the controller or service. The view shouldn't be used to manage controller logic

Answer (score 0):

Well it is because it is because the array has not been evaluated in javascript.Use a call back function and store that array in a variable on the $scope scope.Then you can use it in the function